# How do I fix my test function for swap method in rust?

Tags: testing, rust

So, I wrote a program to swap two numbers in rust, and I've pasted the code below along with it's test function.  My swap() and main() methods work and correctly swap the values in my program when I run cargo run, but when I run cargo test it won't compile, and I'm not sure how to correct my test function.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing in my function, or if I wrote it incorrectly entirely?  Thanks!

```
    fn swap(a: &mut u32, b: &mut u32) {
    let temp: u32 = *a;         // stores value of a in temp
    *a = *b;                    // assigns the value of b to a
    *b = temp;                  // assigns the value of temp (which is a) to b
                                // values are now swapped
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 26;             // assigns value 26.0 to a
    let mut b = 10;             // assigns value 10.0 to b
    
    println!{"Before swap: "};
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);   // prints orginal values for a and b

    swap(&mut a, &mut b);       // calls swap funciton

    println!("After swap: ");
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);   // prints the swapped values for a and b (expecting "10, 26")
}

#[test]
fn test_swap() {
    assert!(swap(&mut 26, &mut 10) == 10u32, 26u32);
}
```

Comment: `swap` doesn't return anything. You can't compare its return value to anything (but `()`, I guess) because there is none.

Answer (score 2):

Your `swap` function takes a couple of mutable references, works over there and does not returns anything.

So when your making `assert!(swap(...) == 10u32, 26u32)` your making `assert!( () ==  10u32, 26u32)` which have 2 errors.

First left part your trying compare `()` with something different of `()`.

And two, but even more fundamentally your writing a bad expression, 10u32, 26u32 are two different members, is like your making something like `if true == true, false` `if 10 == 26, 10`. I mean something with this form `if left == right, a_third_member_senseless`.

Probably your test should looks like this:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_swap() {
    let mut a = 10u32;
    let mut b = 26u32;

    swap(&mut a, &mut b);

    assert_eq!(a, 26u32);
    assert_eq!(b, 10u32);
}
```

You change the value with your function and then, verify the final state of your values.

Comment: actually yes!, I did not realize until now that you comment it